# I have a Gardner Denver RBS 145/LHBD Blower, Compatible oil level sensor?

Tags: oil, sensor, compressor, heater-blower, oil-level

We have a Gardner Denver RBS 145/LHBD blower which shut off due to a low oil level.

The sight glass for the oil level is in an inconvenient spot that also is potentially hazardous to get to while the machine is running.

I would like to install a low oil level sensor so I can set up an alarm.

However, I haven't the first clue how to check compatibility.

Any ideas?

Thank you so much.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: What kind of motor vehicle is this blower mounted on? You want to add an alarm and you want to know what oil level sensor you can use with that unspecified alarm that does not yet exist? This is, uh, fuzzy logic if you'll excuse the expression. What kind of sensor does the alarm require? NO/NC dry contact? 4-20 mA current loop? 0-5 volt? PWM input? You might get better support over at Stack Exchange for Raspberry Pi or for Arduino, where they interface with sensors for fun and profit.

Comment: If the only time oil level checks can be performed and access was not against safety, is it performed only while this blower is running? Is this blower on 24/7 that makes it unsafe to check levels? With limited access, can a mirror or live camera be aimed to view capacity from a distance? Did you consult with the manufacturer for advice?

Comment: @FDryer Live camera: BINGO! There are inexpensive USB flexible borescopes. One could be permanently mounted to focus on the sight glass and plugged into a phone to view the oil level remotely as needed. Not an alarm, but solves the safety problem.

Comment: @MTA This blower is not mounted on a motor vehicle. I asked this question on electronics and was directed here. This blower is used for the primary air at a nonwovens mill. A PNP sensor with 4-20 mA, or 0-10V would work fine, as long as it has the ability to interface with a plc card.

Comment: @FDryer This blower runs 24/7. I have contacted the manufacturer with no feedback as of yet. I was told I would get a call/email in response.

Comment: So far I have been looking at the following options:https://www.reventec.com/product/ls1000-an-10-threaded-liquid-level-sensor/

Comment: Hopefully, the manufacturer gives you a response as recommended from a liability point of view. If nothing, then you have alternative options to suit your needs for operational purposes to customize either indirect view with mirror arrangement or live camera view, switchable for on/off use designed as idiot proof as possible without compromising scheduled or unscheduled oil level checks.

Comment: @Cyange Since this question may be closed at any time because it is not motor-vehicle related, I think the Arduino SE site is a better choice if an alarm is your goal and may be the most responsive. See for example this question and its several ingenious answers: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/501